# Select elements with different classes in jquery

Tags: jquery

can i select Elements of different classes at a time?

suppose if i have

```
      <div id="divAdd">
        <p style="font-size:16px; color:Blue; "></p>
        <p class="test">

            <input:textbox id="id1" type:"text" />

         </p>

        <p class="test">

            <input id="txtMobile" type="text" style="width:120px;" name="txtMobile">
        </p>

        <p class="test">
            <input id="txtMobile" type="text" style="width:120px;"      name="txtMobile">
        </p>

       <p class="child">

       <input id="txtMobile" type="text" style="width:120px;" name="txtMobile">

     </p>
```

can i select all textboxes in two different classes in this way??

```
 $('#divAdd .test input:text','#divAdd .child input:text').each(function () {

    count++;

      });
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$('#divAdd .test input:text, #divAdd .child input:text')
```

Or for better performance:

```
$('#divAdd').find('.test, .child').find('input:text')
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the quotes here, you can use comma `,` to separate **[multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**:

```
$('#divAdd .test input:text, #divAdd .child input:text').each(function () {
```

Also note that:

```
<input:textbox id="id1" type:"text" />
```

is not a valid HTML markup, you need to remove `:textbox` here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `','`. You just need a `,`

```
$('#divAdd .test input:text,#divAdd .child input:text')
```

Just use `,` to separate the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$('#divAdd .test input:text').add('#divAdd .child input:text')
```

***Side Note:*** Textbox id's must be unique!

Answer (score 0):

try this, using double quotes

```
$("#divAdd .test input:text,#divAdd .child input:text").each(function () {
```

or

```
$.merge($("selector"), $("selector"));
```